# Java KeyEvent.VK_??? Whats this key?

Tags: java, keyboard, key

[image]

I just can't find the name of it.

Comment: I believe it's [VK_CONTEXT_MENU](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_CONTEXT_MENU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement a key listener with something like

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key pressed: " + e.getKeyCode()); 
}
```

and then it displays the Keycode of the key.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this one (from the KeyEvent.java code):

```
/**
 * Constant for the Microsoft Windows Context Menu key.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static final int VK_CONTEXT_MENU             = 0x020D;
```